# Advance Sliding Menu in android

Tags: android, android-animation, slidingmenu, android-sliding

Hello Friends i want to implement sliding Menu i like IOS 7 in android below is the URL how is one implemented in IOS.

[image] https://raw2.github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu/master/Demo.gif

for view full animation please visit above URL.

i want to implement same in android.

for implementing this my strategy is i am taking frame layout and using scale and Translation animation together.

if someone already implemented such type of view or have some thought about it so please share.

Comment: Try using this link, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/. Definitely you need to do changes but this will help you some what to complete your goal.

Comment: @InnocentKiller i am able to do such type of old sliding menus please view https://raw2.github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu/master/Demo.gif this GIF i want to implement exactly same.

Comment: Did anyone get it to work like ios 7? Really looking forward to it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what u were looking for :)

https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu